# Successful login redirects to another firewall's default_target_path

Tags: symfony

I have the following "security.yml" configuration and upon successful login as "member" I am being redirected to "administration_index".

What I am trying to achieve is to redirect "root" users to "administration_index" and regular users ("members") to "members_index".

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_MEMBER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ROOT:          ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, users]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    root:   { password: 3Qbg9rthce5, roles: 'ROLE_ROOT' }
                    member: { password: 3Qbg9rthce5, roles: 'ROLE_MEMBER' }
    firewalls:
        administration:
            pattern:    ^/administration
            form_login:
                login_path:                     login
                check_path:                     login_check
                csrf_provider:                  form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path:            administration_index
                always_use_default_target_path: false
            logout:
                ...
        members:
            pattern:    ^/secured
            form_login:
                login_path:                     login
                check_path:                     login_check
                csrf_provider:                  form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path:            members_index
                always_use_default_target_path: false
            logout:
                ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/administration, roles: ROLE_ROOT}
        - { path: ^/administration/users, roles: ROLE_ROOT}
        - { path: ^/secured, roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna do that:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_MEMBER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ROOT:          ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, users]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    root:   { password: 3Qbg9rthce5, roles: 'ROLE_ROOT' }
                    member: { password: 3Qbg9rthce5, roles: 'ROLE_MEMBER' }
    firewalls:
        administration:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                login_path:                     login
                check_path:                     login_check
                csrf_provider:                  form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path:            common_index
                always_use_default_target_path: false
            logout:
                ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/administration, roles: ROLE_ROOT}
        - { path: ^/secured, roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
```

Then, in your `common_index` controller, you can do something like (I assume your in a standard controller inheriting from the controller of the framework bundle):

```
if ($this
    ->get('security.context')
    ->getToken()
    ->getUser()
    ->hasRole('ROLE_ROOT')) {
    return $this->forward('administration_index');
}

return $this->forward('members_index');
```

You can use `redirect` instead of `forward` if you consider that this is a redirection.

Comment: I thought about this "dispatcher" approach but I'm still hoping it can be achieved with configuration.

Comment: This cannot be achieved with configuration without [any conding](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/target_path.html) or external bundle. When, you define 2 firewalls it has some repercussions. This choice shouldn't be made just to have different target paths.